# как удалить значение поля в таблице mysql если заранее не известно в каком именно поле оно хранится

Tags: php, mysql

имеется таблица mysql со столбцами
id1
id2
id3
в одном из них есть значение userid, как удалить значение userid из ячейки столбца если заранее не известно в какой именно колонке оно хранится без предвартельного перебора ячеек на совпадение и написания трех разных функций?

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE table
SET field1 = CASE WHEN field1 = @id THEN 0 ELSE field1 END,
SET field2 = CASE WHEN field2 = @id THEN 0 ELSE field2 END,
SET field3 = CASE WHEN field3 = @id THEN 0 ELSE field3 END
WHERE @id IN (field1, field2, field3)
```

Comment: риспект спасибо))